# Is it possible to increase audio volume on system sound?

Tags: iphone, ios, audiotoolbox

I am making piano application for iPad. I am using `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound` (toneSSID) for play sound of keys. But there also functionality to increase volume. But I not find how to increase sound. Can anybody help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add  AudioStreamer.h file

Add this method to AudioStreamer.m

```
- (void)setVolume:(float)Level
{

OSStatus errorMsg = AudioQueueSetParameter(audioQueue, kAudioQueueParam_Volume, Level);

if (errorMsg) {
    NSLog(@"AudioQueueSetParameter returned %d when setting the volume.", errorMsg);
}

}
```

And handle this to audiostreamclass object like

AudioStreamer *Obj = [AudioStreamer alloc] init];

```
[obj setVolume:1.0];
```

Comment: can u tell me what is audioQueue here